# Breaking out of while loop and sleep

Tags: c#, mouseevent

I'm trying to make a very simple autoclicker in C# just to get better at it.

I have a form with two numeric text boxes and two buttons. The first text box specifies how much time should be between each click (in msec), and the second text box specifies the number of iterations.

The first button I have is `button1`, which essentially just starts the program. I have a second button called `button2`, which will stop the `button1_Click` function.

Here's what I have:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //While a is less than number of specified iterations
    for (int a = 0; a < Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown2.Value); a++)
    {
        //Sleep for desired time
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value));

        //Get x/y coordinates of mouse
        int X = Cursor.Position.X;
        int Y = Cursor.Position.Y;

        //Click mouse at x/y coordinates
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);
    }
}

public void Form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

My problem is that my program is stuck in that for loop, and I have no way to break the `button1_Click` function.

I want it so that if I press F11 or my `button2` button, the `button1_Click` function will immediately stop, but the form itself will still be open. Right now I'm just using the `ESC` key just for simplicity.

Comment: You're sleeping the UI thread so the app *will* become unresponsive. Oou need to look at using a proper timer.

Comment: In WPF/C# you may use RepeatButton as detailed here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750603(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Could you just do a while loop in button one that is while button 2 is not activated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a 'Timer' object to your form, set it's Interval to the number of milliseconds to 'sleep' (not really). Set it's Enabled property to false.

Handle it's Tick event and put all of your inner-loop code there (the mouse_event call).

In button1_Click (buttonStart would be a better name), set the timer Enabled to true, and in button2_Click (buttonStop) set the timer Enabled to false.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
public Timer myTimer { get; set; }

public Form()
{
   myTimer = new Timer();
   myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
   myTimer.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value);
   myTimer.Start();
}

public void Form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
    {
        myTimer.Stop();
        this.Close();
    }
}

private static void TimerEventProcessor(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
{
    //Get x/y coordinates of mouse
    int X = Cursor.Position.X;
    int Y = Cursor.Position.Y;
    //Click mouse at x/y coordinates
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Timer t1;
int ticks = 0;
bool timerInitialized = false
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!timerInitialized)
  {
    t1 = new Timer();
    t1.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    timerInitialized = true;
  }
  button1.Enabled = false;
  t1.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value);
  ticks = 0;
  t1.Start();
}

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (ticks <  Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown2.Value))
  {
    ticks++;

    //Get x/y coordinates of mouse
    int X = Cursor.Position.X;
    int Y = Cursor.Position.Y;
    //Click mouse at x/y coordinates
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);
  }
  else
  {
    t1.Stop(); //You could Call Stop from every where e.g. from another Button
    button1.Enabled = true;
  }
}
```

EDIT:
Assign the "Tick" event only once

Comment: You are delegating the Timer_Tick method on every Button1 click. This is not good.